# CloudFront & Route 53: The alias target name does not lie within the target zone

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront, amazon-route53

I keep getting this error code:

> [Tried to create an alias that targets d1rjnk9azrfd0f.cloudfront.net., type A in zone Z04732832HJZEKNE8JUGT, but the alias target name does not lie within the target zone, Tried to create an alias that targets d1rjnk9azrfd0f.cloudfront.net., type A in zone Z04732832HJZEKNE8JUGT, but that target was not found] UPDATE_ROLLBACK_IN_PROGRESS AWS::CloudFormation::Stack cloud-resume The following resource(s) failed to create: [MyRoute53Record]. This is my code: MyRoute53Record: Type: "AWS::Route53::RecordSetGroup" Properties: HostedZoneId: Z04732832HJZEKNE8JUGT RecordSets: - Name: website.cloudrookie.com Type: A AliasTarget: HostedZoneId: Z04732832HJZEKNE8JUGT DNSName: !GetAtt MyDistribution.DomainName

I believe my `HostedZoneId` under my Alias Target is supposed to be pointed to something else.

I tried changing my `HostedZoneId` to whatever my CDN Id was and that did not work. I read that it might be my S3 bucket zone ID, if that is true I do not know where to find it

This is the code I'm using:

```
MyRoute53Record:
    Type: "AWS::Route53::RecordSetGroup"
    Properties:
      HostedZoneId: Z04732832HJZEKNE8JUGT
      RecordSets:
        - Name: website.cloudrookie.com
          Type: A
          AliasTarget:
            HostedZoneId: Z04732832HJZEKNE8JUGT
            DNSName: !GetAtt MyDistribution.DomainName
```

Answer (score 1):

Hosted Zone IDs are different per service (Cloudfront, ALB, …) and per region.

The hosted zone ID for Cloudfront, however, is always `Z2FDTNDATAQYW2`, as per [AWS documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-route53-aliastarget-1.html).

Comment: This was so easy to miss. Thank you!